# Tomcat 8 + OPenJDK 8 64 bit - memory usage

Tags: tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, java

I have a tomcat 8 webapp running in Elastic Beanstalk on OpenJDK 8 64 bit.

JMX says that the committed heap+nonheap is 1 GB. Top says that the java process uses 1.3 GB.

Where are the 0.3 GB memory?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

On the heap, being used by the JVM's own things, not accessible to your software.